# My username is forced to change because it is close to that of a well-known user

Tags: support, etiquette, moderators, new-users, display-names

I received suddenly an email from the Moderation Team:

> Hello,
>
> We're writing in reference to your Mathematics Stack Exchange account:
>
> https://math.stackexchange.com/users/798202/user798202
>
> We reset your display-name as amWily is very close to amWhy that of a
> well-known user. Now, even identical user names are possible, but due
> to the rather distinctive nature it was noteworthy enough to contact
> you, mostly to understand your intent.
>
> Regards, Mathematics Stack Exchange Moderation Team

I have NEVER EVER expected that I must not use a username that is close to other users' ones.

During almost the same time period of getting the email, which disrespectfully questions my intent, four of my answers were also downvoted.

Why?! I did not do anything but answering a few questions to help others. Why am I treated so badly simply because my name coincides with another user's one?!

Comment: They seem to be expecting a response from you as to why you chose that username.

Comment: Regarding the last part, if you believe that the downvotes were an act of "target-downvoting" (as a revenge perhaps) I'd encourage flagging.

Comment: Your username used a format similar to the well-known user [amWhy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9003/amwhy), with a variation that replaces "Why" with "[Wily](https://www.google.co.in/search?source=hp&ei=UzbuXpbiHfOO4-EPgYe9mAk&q=wily+meaning&oq=wily+meaning&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIFCAAQsQMyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAA6BQgAEIMBUIYCWMcNYJkOaABwAHgAgAHJAogBoQ2SAQcwLjkuMC4ymAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjW182j5ZDqAhVzxzgGHYFDD5MQ4dUDCAc&uact=5)". The mentioned user is known to be targeted by some users, usually by means of downvotes and malicious edits.

Comment: In light of that, it's not unreasonable for your username to have attracted attention. You may have chosen your username innocently, but in this case it might be better to speak to the moderators to try and figure out what ought to be done. I don't think it will be fruitful to open such a Meta discussion, especially one written emotionally.

Comment: Well I see nothing abnormal here since many answers have been downvoted. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727007/find-minimum-of-x2-frac1x-for-x0/3727050#3727050  Plus your answer has been upvoted three times and is accepted as an answer. Maybe you're talking about another question or answer ?

Comment: Tangential topic, but the downvote on the answer posted on the closed question might be due to some users trying to discourage answering questions that shouldn't be answered in the first place (thus, closed).

Comment: I think some very important info can be found in the OP's profile (as we were suggested to check more often during the CoC changes...) and I quote: "おはようございます

My name is **Amily**." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @CalvinKhora as a matter of fact the sentence "My name is Amily" was not present when the message quoted in the meta post was written. I did however translate the bit in Japanese.

Comment: @quid also good to know. For the lazy, its just good morning ('just', given how charged any information could be in this Question)

Comment: To make it clear, your username is not problematic because it resembles another one. It is probematic because it can (and will) be seen as an attempt to attack that other user. We could also discuss whether amWhy has a trademark on this particular spelling of "Amy", but that is rather irrelevant here. The debacle with Monica Cellio made it a popular fad to edit one's username to make a statement. That has never been an issue, because the target of those protests was not any single individual. This is different, and I want to commend the moderator team for wanting to nip this in the bud.

Comment: I think it is better to respond to mods in private and bring it on meta only when things are not resolved to your satisfaction. Also you should compare the tone of the mail from mods with the tone in this post.

Answer (score 8):

There is no problem in itself with close or identical usernames. There is a quite active user quid on money.se that is not me. There are any number of users named John, some of them likely actually named John others just picking it as some common name. And so on.

This was also said in the message: "even identical user names are possible."

The message does not in itself amount to a prohibition of the use of this display-name. As mentioned in comments it is a request for information. Reasons why the question is asked are also suggested in comments.

The situation seemed unclear. Thus, we decided to ask for clarification. Maybe the choice is independent, maybe it is related. If it is related, it could be related in a positive, neutral or negative way.

It's not quite the same if you pick amWily because you admire amWhy's contributions or if instead you pick amWily to spite amWhy.
Or, for something in the middle, noted the name amWhy found it a neat idea and modified it for your purpose not thinking it would cause much issue.

We also can not know in advance if this is very relevant to you. I used an SE site for a quite a long time without particular display name. At some point I was encouraged to pick one to avoid confusions (back in the day there was not even a numbering). So, I came up with quid. Further, had somebody told me back then we prefer you not use quid for some reason, I might just have changed to something else. If you'd want me to change now, that'd be a bit different, but then you just joined.

If it is very important to you to keep the name, we will need to see how to proceed. But if it is not, then maybe you could do us a favor and just pick something else (rather than to insist on your right to pick your displayname) and we all move on.

In advance, we cannot even know if it is important to you whence we started an exchange about the subject.

The issue with the votes is orthogonal. *If* the votes are due to the usename issue that's not alright *even if* the usernamme would be found to be problematic. But there are many 'if' there. Better to focus on one subject at a time.

Comment: What is the purpose of knowing the intent? It doesn't seem like that matters or would change anything.

Comment: Off-topic, but the username _quid_ on money.se seems rather intelligent to me

Comment: @PaulPlummer maybe the word is not ideal, the idea was to get some understanding for the reason for the choice.

Comment: “…maybe you could do us a favor and just pick something else…” This whole sentence makes it sound like the username amWily creates a great inconvenience for you, which it doesn’t. It’s similar but clearly different from amWhy; personally I don’t struggle to recognise the difference between the letter h and the letters il, but I suppose I can’t speak for others and their reading levels.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish as a matter of fact the existence of that username does create a lot of work for me. You are free to think that  this should not be the case, but this does not alter the fact that it does create it. So, yes, if there is no very strong reason to keep that name I think it should be changed. Thus, far I do not see any good reason not to change it. Mostly it all seems to create a spectacle on meta for no good reason. Of course this is likely entirely non-intentional.

Comment: @quid What work does it create for you? If that’s the case, I might change my mind, not that anyone cares.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish you know full well that I had about 20 inbox messages on this post here. That is the work.

Comment: I guess what I was getting at is that the reason/intent doesn't really matter; if for whatever reason the name is unacceptable then that is it. There is a history of being very lenient on choice of names, which I am pretty sure you have written answers to that effect before, so I am somewhat surprised and find this silly(I don't much care either way tbh). Also, I think the 20 inbox messages is work you/mods created, blaming the OP seems a bit unfair. While we are discussing resetting names I would like resetting names of historical people, especially historical mathematicians

Comment: I find them in bad taste even with the best of intentions (Just in case it isn't clear, I am being serious)

Comment: @PaulPlummer a couple of points in no particular order. First, of all about half of those 20  messages came from gen-z specifically to whom I was talking and who does not even have any particular stake in this. They flooded my inbox and then a couple minutes later tell me they don't get at all how this creates work for me. Second, OP could have continued the exchange with the moderators rather than voicing their grieve here. They were not suspended or anything. Nothing particularly bad happened to them. Their reaction strikes me as way overblown and frankly does not raise confidence.

Comment: Third there is a major difference between display names that are somehow silly, in bad taste, maybe borderline vulgar etc. and a display name that looks like it is directly inspired by that of another user; in particular in a way that can be seen as having negative connotations. Several users confirmed that the impression one can get is that this name was taken to target another user. This is not even similar,  it is an entirely different concern.

Comment: I don't think that if there is a credible risk that a user of this site is targeted we can just ignore that. The only question is maybe is that risk credible. Well, I would say, definitetly, yes. Some users like gen-z seem to argue there is no major risk of confusion and thus it is fine, but that really misses the point. The first question to ask is: was the choice **entirely** independent, that is does the choice of this display name have nothing at all to do with the existence of amWhy. Frankly, I find that pretty unlikely and even eg gen-z also did not commit to saying that.

Comment: Alright, that is fair enough. I personally didn't read it as targeting or an attack on amWhy but it does seem like a lot of people (including amWhy) see it that way so I have no problem with the enforcement of the name change.  Also, I don't think the choice was independent of the existence of amWhy but I am not really sure why it would have to be to make the name ok in the eyes of the moderators. Whether or not the name was inspired or not seems independent of whether or not the name is acceptable.

Comment: Basically, I just think it makes more sense to just come out and say that the choice of name is perceived as targeting a particular user, and is hurtful, rather than trying to extract some reason (and what reason would be good enough for mods to change the decision) for the choice of name. I also disagree with the whole accepting bad taste names, which I can see amWily as one, but I think that would be a losing battle on my part.

Comment: I was getting to that @PaulPlummer  And as soon as there is a relation, it raises questions, also as to what the point of taking inspiration in another user's name is. If it is done without ill-intentions or even in a friendly spirit  yet the copied  user does not appreciate it, then the right thing to do is to just drop the matter and to take another display name. The rest is a matter of communication. What you suggest at least implicitly accuses OP more of ill intent than what I wrote (at least that was my intent). With my message they can just 'walk away' from it.

Comment: No disrespect or offense intended to anyone, but you **cannot** ask whether this issue causes fuss to the moderators or not _unless_ you have been in their shoes. @quid your point has been made clear and I see no point -other than fatigue- in justifying your/ the mods' decision in questioning the username

Comment: Surely everyone has the right to debate mods' decisions.. but just don't forget that they are mods for several notable reasons

Comment: @amWhy please point it out so that i can make necessary clarifications :)

Comment: @OmarS I cannot know if it is the same for amWhy but what is not exactly clear to me is what you mean by "I see no point -other than fatigue- in justifying". Maye the exact sense of 'fatigue' is the issue.

Comment: @quid I meant that you were asked to justify what happened to the OP and you did answer **comprehensively** .. my point is that you refrain from justifying yourself further because you already have! :) The objections are becoming more and more emotional and subjective and hence inconclusive..

Comment: After reading this answer i wonder why wouldnt the mods team asks for clarification **before** changing their username. That seems quite rude.

Comment: @ArcticChar how long exactly would we need to wait for a reply? It's just not practical..The changed username does really not change much for the user. Anyway, we do that with some frequency. *Usually* there is no problem. If anything the actions of the user past the change, seem to confirm that it was right to change the username. It seems clear, and seemed clear,  to me that this is bad-faith actor: The initial actions gave them an easy out in case it was more a prank than malice. They did not take it, unfortunately.

Comment: I just read the whole comments and it seems that Paul has spoken most of my thought (which you have responded, sorry for that). Just another one: What replies do you expect from that user so that they can use amWily?

Comment: @ArcticChar something that might have convinced me would likely have been documentation of using it intensely elsewhere. If the user had said they do it out of fandom for amWhy we might have put amWhy in the loop to see if she is fine with having a visible fanboy or fangirl on the site. That said, as I wrote, I did not really expect to receive a convincing answer. The idea was to diffuse the situation. It is not clear what exact alternative route you propose.

Comment: The by far likeliest scenario, essentially a certainty by now,  is that it is just an attempt at trolling. I won't go out of my way to reason with a troll. If ever they  want a constructive exchange about it, they first explain what they were doing. I opened up a channel of communication. That's all. As said maybe the word "intent" was not ideal but ultimately it would not have changed anything. To reiterate, it was a near certainty that the account was created for the purpose  of creating problems, and it only became more certain ever since. But I won't write that in the message. @ArcticChar

Answer (score -2):

I disagree with the moderators’ decision. I don’t have trouble distinguishing them, and this user is obviously not trying to impersonate amWhy.

There’s also the issue of precedent. As quid brings up, there are many users named John. Will we start allowing only one John?

If you **agree** that amWily should be allowed to **keep** this username, **upvote this post**.

Comment: (-1) Every time I saw the user name "amWily", I thought "There's someone having a go at amWhy, for some reason." Maybe they were, maybe they weren't, but either way, it's a nuisance for there to be such a close and *apparently* intentional clash of names. The moderators were right to question the choice.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Why do you think the clashing of the names is intentional? Are you saying you think the OP is trying to impersonate amWhy?

Comment: I *emphasised* the word 'apparently', in order to make it as clear as I could that I was not taking a position on whether the clash was intentional! I wonder whether even one person other than you misunderstood my meaning.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish "Why do you think the clashing of the names is intentional?" Are you sure the choice of the  username amWily was **entirely** unrelated to the existence/presence of amWhy?

Comment: @quid Hmm… I don’t think there’s even a preponderance of evidence—presented here—that there was intent to trick others into thinking this user is amWhy. Have the moderators uncovered any evidence to the contrary? I’d be very interested to see it.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish answer what I asked not what you want to answer.

Comment: @quid Okay. I don’t know if there’s a connection between amWily and amWhy as there’s no evidence. Either way, a connection isn’t a problem. The problem is if any trickery occurs, intentional or unintentional. I can distinguish them just fine, and it sounds like Calum Gilhooley can too. There’s no evidence of intent to trick either.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish no it is also a problem if one user chooses a username with the intent to annoy another user.

Comment: @quid True! There’s no evidence that I see of intent though.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish the first evidence is the low likelihood of it happening entirely independently. That's the difference to 'John.'  However, ultimately the intent is even somewhat irrelevant. The perception is present as several users, also entirely independent ones, confirmed. Once this is present it is a problem that should be addressed in some way.

Comment: I don't need to prove beyond a reasonable doubt that the username was chosen with malicious intent. If it objectively creates issues and there is no very good reason to keep it, it changes. Those resisting this change should ask themselves what actually motivates them.

Comment: Is it still not clear? Really? I don't want to comment again, but here goes, just one more time. I have no idea if there was any intention to needle amWhy. It *looked* that way to me, and evidently it *looked* that way to others, too. Even the mere fact that it looked that way is, self-evidently, a problem. Therefore the moderators were right to *question* the choice. There still seems to be no answer to their question, just a lot of premature sounding-off and inaccurate attribution of opinions. Please don't make me comment again! I'm no mind-reader; nor are you reading my mind correctly.

Comment: Let me add one more remark. The not searching for evidence and just changing the name is potentially also in OP's favor. The door is open and they can just walk away from the name and that's that. By contrast if we are pushed to prove malicious intent and do so the consequences would be more severe. We did nothing that effects that  user particularly negatively.

Comment: gen-z Don't be daft. Impersonation is not the problem here.

Comment: barely +1, I just feel like forcing OP to tiptoe around a user, if OP is innocent, can only breed resentment, so I think I would not have taken the same actions as the mods.

Comment: Amily doesn't resemble amWily in any way, @Calvin Knor.  The user, on their profile, as you note, claimed their name was Amily, after they got the message from the mods.  Then why did they not choose `@Amily` as a username  which is clearly different than @amWily, no? Why the lowercase am, and insertion of the uppercase W, in the middle of their claim name?  ...  If you can't see the tenuous nature of this users proposed and defeated username, then you are willingly wanting to remain hoodwinked.

Comment: @amWhy It's surely deliberate, but not necessarily malicious (though that's a natural first impression). It might be some combination of affectionate/admiring/humorous, for example. You may have made a good impression on Amily! (If that's her name.) One can only speculate - until the mods' enquiry receives a response, if it ever does. (Damn, I've commented again.)

Comment: I agree with a lot of things that have been said, in particular I agree (contrary to my +1 on this Answer) that no one has been 'impersonating' amWhy and it is more akin to referencing or maybe even parody. I'm not so sure that there is enough space in so few letters to see malice so easily. I just don't think that a mod should proactively punish potential wrongdoers.

Comment: By the way, I'm very very *very* amused that both @amWny and @quida$\le\ge$ mispelled my (user)name, in the context of this question no less! Shall I assume it is intentional? Or should I assume good faith of all actors involved?

Comment: @CalvinKhor in my case it was an editing error and I would say that is the plausible assumption. There is no reason to think otherwise (what would have been the point?) and the "a" from the subsequent word somehow arrive there. I did not even know about that error until now.  On the other hand *I* would say that amWhy clearly did it on purpose to make a point. And I don't think that she would seriously claim otherwise. (I also think that in the context of the debate this is alright; if it would persist systematically that'd be different.)

Answer (score -6):

I feel very frustrated.

My username contains no curse words, and I am not at all making fun of other's names. Only a police officer would ask someone's "intent" like that. The email message makes me feel very disrespected.

After getting the email, I informed the Moderator Team that my name is Amily. I also added that extra info to my website profile. I could have not disclose such information at all. I think this would be more than enough to clarify the situation even if there happened to be any misunderstanding.

Please reinstate my username.

Comment: You are asking the moderators to take some specific action.  Answering your question on meta is not a good way to make that happen.  It is best to contact the moderators directly (or, if they are unresponsive, escalate to the community moderation team).

Comment: re "Only a police officer would" It's not very clear what the point of that remark is. I mean in part moderators are the police officers of this site.

Comment: Was using *amilWhy* not an option? That would not suffer from the same baggage.